# Postbuild macro throws 9009 error on compilation

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2015

Im running the macro

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug "xcopy /R /Y $(ProjectDir)Configuration\* $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
```

after i have built the project.
The purpose of this line is to detect Debug Compile Mode, and in that case overwrite a dll with another dll that contains simmed values.

Thats why i included the /R /Y in the xcopy

All the files that need to be copied are in the Configuration Folder within the ProjectDir.

Im not sure if im missing some copy parameter, that prevents me from overwriting a dll or if the string has some sorta error in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My formating was off, i figured it out

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
xcopy /R /Y "$(ProjectDir)Configuration\*" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
)
```